# Thymleaf - how to call model Attribute on html document

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot, thymeleaf

Im trying to render a webapge and use the thymleaf attribute "url" added with model.addAttribute but the Attribute is not beeing displayed on the html document.
My document.html file path is here:

/templates/webpage/document.html

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/webpage/document")
    public String document(HttpServletRequest req, Model model) {

        model.addAttribute("dialogurl", url);
        return "/webpage/document";
    }
```

Here is the html document

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org" th:include="wrapperdialog :: page">
<head>
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
<div th:fragment="content">
    <div class="container dialogpage">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-12">
                <div id="typeform" th:attr="data-url=*{dialogurl}">
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please use this expression to bind dialog url: `@{${dialogurl}}`

```
<div id="typeform" th:attr="data-url=@{${dialogurl}}">
```

`@` prefix is used to specify a link and `$` prefix is used to bind your model value.

Comment: Is there a way to add this to an html form? Or does it only work with div component? I use spring boot with html pages, and when I add this code and modify it, I get `Caused by: org.attoparser.ParseException: Could not parse as assignation sequence: "/index.html=@{${index}}" (template: "index" - line 43, col 75)` error.

Comment: By the way the reason I'm trying to use this component because the error I was getting forced me to use `modelAttribute` component, and since it doesn't work with html (it is used in .jsp forms) I found your answer as an alternative way to solution.

Comment: Are you binding value to form input ?

Comment: You can use `th:value`

Answer (score 0):

Use `$` to bind data.

`<div id="typeform" th:attr="data-url=${dialogurl}">`